# Dynamic created checkbox using foreach in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, foreach, checkboxlist

I have list page to show all images with its name from database in asp.net mvc list action (PhotoList - get).. in that view page (PhotoList.aspx), I have created checkbox to delete multiple rows. I want scenario like following

First page shows the list with in first column checkbox and in second column PhotoName and on the down page one button for delete selected rows .
when selects checkboxes and clicks the delete button, according to selection the rows will be deleted from database and return the same list page..

I don't understand where to write code for delete and how?

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <input type="checkbox" name="deleteImage" value="<%= item.PhotoId %>"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PhotoId }) %> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.PhotoName) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
<input type="button" name="Delete" value="Delete Selected items"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code for delete will be written in the HttpPost action for delete. Something like below should work if you are using `myModel`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(myModel deleteEntries) //This is the post-version of your Action that rendered the view..If it's Edit, then change the name to Edit
{
    var deleteList = db.deleteEntries.where(d => d.checkBox == true).ToList();
    foreach (myList my in deleteList)
    {
        db.myList.Remove(my); // remember db should be your DbContext instace
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**UPDATE**

You will first need to make a ViewModel because otherwise you cannot recognize which entries are checked for deletion with the help of checkbox.

Make a ViewMode class like following

```
using pratice3.Models; 
public class MyPhotoViewModel
{
    public UserManagementDbEntities.tblPhoto TablePhoto { get; set; }
    public bool checkBox { get; set; }
}
```

Return this to your view

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] 
public ActionResult PhotosList() 
{
    var viewModel = _datamodel.tblPhoto.Select(g => new MyPhotoViewModel
                                   {
                                       TablePhoto = g;
                                       checkBox = false;
                                   }).ToList();      
    return View(viewModel); 
}
```

In View, change the using statement to reflect `IEnumerable<MyPhotoViewModel>` and make appropriate changes accordingly.

Then, define your Post Action like following

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PhotosList(IEnumerable<MyPhotoViewModel> myPhotoList) 
{
    var deleteList = myPhotoList.where(d => d.checkBox == true).ToList();
    foreach (var deletePhoto in deleteList)
    {
        _datamodel.tblPhoto.DeleteObject(deletePhoto.TablePhoto); 
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: what is "myModel"? and db...?

Comment: i have usermanagementEntitites as model entity and _datamodel as object of that and tblPhoto as table in that .. so how can i do?

Comment: can i know the exactly what are "myModel"  , "myList" and "db" ?

Comment: seems like you have used entity designer? Can you show me the code for the controller which is rendering this view

Comment: using pratice3.Models;                            UserManagementDbEntities _datamodel = new UserManagementDbEntities();
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult PhotosList()
        {
            return View(_datamodel.tblPhoto.ToList());
           
        }

Comment: where i need to create viewmodel?

Comment: where your other class reside. In Model folder

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this.

On button click get all the Ids of photos, something like this

```
  var selected = new Array();
  $('name="deleteImage" input:checked').each(function () {
      selected.push($(this).attr('id')));
  });
  var selectedIds = selected.join(',');
```

Now on button click, make ajax call to some function on server side which will accept these ids and will delete from DB or so.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteRecord", "UserManage")',
    data: 'ids=' + selectedIds + '&time=' + new Date(), //Date makes each call unique
    success: function (data) {
        //You can reload page
    },
    error: function (data) { 
        //You can show error
    }
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In selectedIds do i receive all the selected id with comma sepreted list? and insted of ajax caling can i pass this string to any action of controller..?

Comment: Yes, you will get comma separated string. And to post data to your action controller, you will need to create model, else it is very easy to make a get request. Updated code, assuming you have DeleteRecord  function accepting comma separated string in UserManageController.